# Print r vector to copy paste into other code.

Tags: r

I have a vector I'd like to copy paste into code to be able to produce a minimal working example.

Problem is, when I try to print the vector it produces output like

```
> head(residuals_list)
            1         2         3         4         5         6
    0.1833777 7.1833777 1.1833777 4.1833777 5.1833777 0.1833777
```

How do I get r to print `c(0.1833777, 7.1833777, ...)`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With `dput` :

```
x =runif(5)
dput(x)

c(0.634340619435534, 0.833359521813691, 0.4804580679629, 0.119585362030193, 
0.379494784167036)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str(residuals_list)` to get a string version of the object