# How to print character vector in "copy-paste" ready list format (e.g "a, b, c")?

Tags: r

I want to print a character vector in R in a way that I can copy and paste it onto a text. Comma-separated, and no quotes.

There are a few similar questions around.

*Dput* prints in a code-ready format ([Print r vector to copy paste into other code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882075/print-r-vector-to-copy-paste-into-other-code)) but keeps the quotes.

The function *noquote* removes the quotes, but also removes the commas ([Remove quotes from a character vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215481/remove-quotes-from-a-character-vector-in-r))

```r
> vec <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
> print(vec)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> dput(vec)
c("a", "b", "c")
> noquote(vec)
[1] a b c
```

I want to have an output like

```
a, b, c
```

or similar.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Use `cat(vec, sep=", ")`

Comment: We can use `cat`(you could also define your own print method) as pointed out by MrFlick above.

Comment: @MrFlick your comment is a good answer. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct? thanks!